# Eloquent 'when' method after another 'when'

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have searched a lot for this but couldn't find related issues.

I have an Eloquent query in my app that is the following:

```
$cidades = Cidade::when($pesquisa, function ($q) use ($pesquisa) {
    return $q->where('nome', 'like', '%' . $pesquisa . '%')
        ->orWhere('iso_ddd', 'like', '%' . $pesquisa . '%');
})
    ->when($estado, function ($q) use ($estado) {
        return $q->where('estado_id', $estado);
    })
    ->sortable('nome')
    ->simplePaginate($request->input('p'));
```

As you can see, I have two 'when' methods to filter the content. My intention is to check wheter each of them are active and filter the query accordingly. But the query above only works if only one of them is active at once. If $pesquisa is set, then it filters the content using the function, but ignores the following 'when' (objects of any $estado show up). If $pesquisa is not set but $estado is, then it correctly runs only the $estado's 'when'.

I could get it to run as excpected by copying $estado's 'when' inside $pesquisa's 'when', like this:

```
$cidades = Cidade::when($pesquisa, function ($q) use ($pesquisa, $estado) {
    return $q->where('nome', 'like', '%' . $pesquisa . '%')
        ->when($estado, function ($q) use ($estado) {
            return $q->where('estado_id', $estado);
        })
        ->orWhere('iso_ddd', 'like', '%' . $pesquisa . '%');
})
    ->when($estado, function ($q) use ($estado) {
        return $q->where('estado_id', $estado);
    })
    ->sortable('nome')
    ->simplePaginate($request->input('p'));
```

But I find it a bit redundant. Is there any other way to query it?

Comment: How did you get `$pesquisa` and `$estado` variables? Do you sure they return boolean values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is the fact that there's an `or` involved. This is what you get when both are set:

```
SELECT * FROM cidades WHERE nom LIKE ? OR iso_ddd LIKE ? AND estado_id = ?
```

Due to `AND` having higher associativity to `OR` this would get all records where `nom LIKE ? OR (iso_ddd LIKE ? AND estado_id = ?)` which is not exactly what you seem to want.

You can try:

```
$cidades = Cidade::when($pesquisa, function ($q) use ($pesquisa) {
    return $q->where(function ($q) use ($pesquisa) {
          $q->where('nome', 'like', '%' . $pesquisa . '%')
           ->orWhere('iso_ddd', 'like', '%' . $pesquisa . '%');
       });
    })->when($estado, function ($q) use ($estado) {
        return $q->where('estado_id', $estado);
    })
    ->sortable('nome')
    ->simplePaginate($request->input('p'));
```

this should put parentheses around `(nom = ? or iso_ddd = ?)` to ensure the conditions are grouped correctly.

Comment: I've now found another solution that I posted, but yours is very nice too, it does put those parenthesis in the right place.

Comment: Good point. I think you prefer this @Alexandre. Because multiple where must be grouped for sql confusions. Also you may think to separate `when` filterings. Your codebase will be more understandable with this way. Check second code example: https://laraveldaily.com/less-know-way-conditional-queries/

Comment: That is even better. The way it's shown in the article is indeed better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `when` parameter value to `true`. Then just check the condition inside the `when`

```php
$cidades = Cidade::when(true, function ($q) use ($pesquisa, $estado) {
    if ($estado) {
        return $q->where('estado_id', $estado);
    }

    return $q->where('nome', 'like', '%' . $pesquisa . '%')
        ->orWhere('iso_ddd', 'like', '%' . $pesquisa . '%');
})
->sortable('nome')
->simplePaginate($request->input('p'));
```

Comment: But then if $estado is set, it will return the query filtered only by $estado and skip the rest. I need to filter the query by both arguments.

Comment: You can copy the contents after the `$estado` or even use scopes or this kind of query.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the query log (DB::getQueryLog()) I found out that my problem was related to associativity.

The solution was to put the $estado's `when` before the $pequisa's `when`. That solved it.

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
$cidades = Cidade::when($estado, function ($e) use ($estado) {
    return $e->where('estado_id', $estado);
})
    ->when($pesquisa, function ($q) use ($pesquisa, $estado) {
        return $q->where('nome', 'like', '%' . $pesquisa . '%')
            ->orWhere('iso_ddd', 'like', '%' . $pesquisa . '%');
    })
    ->sortable('nome')
    ->simplePaginate($request->input('p'));
```